# need advice on transformers to power 3v solar outdoor LED bulb string lights

Tags: led, transformer

I bought two strings of outdoor string/patio lights which used 10 x 3v bulbs (per string) and a small solar panel/battery to light them.  Bulbs appear to be wired in parallel.

I decided that I want to replace the solar panel with a small transformer because the bulbs did not stay on long enough.  I cut the cable to the solar panel and battery modules and connected, connected both strings together (giving one string of 20 bulbs) and connected  it to a simple 3v transformer.  Everything works but the bulbs are quite dim.  I want to understand what transformer to use to increase the brightness, and the best way to setup a timer to control them.

(I already have outdoor 110v sockets in a weather protected box, so I have a place to plug in the transformer.  I also have a outdoor transformer that outputs 12vac used to power my landscape lights and automatically turns on at dusk.)

I understand that increasing the voltage is not the right way to increase the brightness of the bulbs, and I need to increases the current.  I also understand that if I put too much current through the bulbs then I will burn them out.  The current 3v transformer that I use outputs 500ma.  I checked it with a multimeter and it actually outputs 2.8vdc.

So I see two solutions and I will appreciate any advice I can get:

1. replace the current transformer with one with higher output current, but I dont understand the topic well enough to not make a mistake.  I always understood that the milliamp rating of the transformer is the maximum it can support before overheating and/or dying, so my first instinct was to just buy a 3v transformer with a much higher Milliamp output rating and let the LED bulbs take as much as they want.  But I read that with LEDs that I dont want too much current, so now I'm afraid that I dont understand how this works and by using a transformer with a much higher milliamp rating I can blow all the bulbs.  So does this make sense?  If I just use a simple 110vac->3vdc transformer, then I can get a smart socket (TP-Link or something similar) to control the lights.
2. Another solution which might be more elegant is to wire the string lights to the 12vac transformer that powers my landscape lights, so the string lights come on at dusk automatically together with the landscape lights.  For this to work, I need to try to find a 12vac to 3vdc transformer and I'm still faced with my uncertainty about how many milliamp I need on the output of the transformer.  And I didn't find any off the shelf transformer from 12vac to 3vdc.

Comment: You have understood it wrong. Even if you hae 3V 10A supply the LEDs would still have 3V and be just as dim. You need to increase voltage.

Comment: Please provide a data sheet for the LED strings.

Comment: You need to find out whether your LED string is voltage driven or current driven, and whether it requires DC or is suitable for AC. Only then you can start thinking about a suitable power supply.

Comment: You measured 2.8VDC at the output of your transformer. But a transformer produces AC with zero DC. LEDs operate with DC but will rectify AC and blink on and off very quickly. The original solar panel and battery produced current-limited DC voltage thaT YOU NEED TO DUPLICATE.

Comment: I should add that the bulbs on the string lights are labeled 3v dc.  I have no datasheet for the LED strings, but they appear to be simple +/- wires with E26 bulb sockets wired in parallel.  The transfer I am using definitely produces DC voltage, it is clear that the output on it is 3v dc 500ma.

Comment: at the point I found some 12v AC LED light bulbs with E26 base on Amazon, and I think the simplest solution is just to change all the bulbs to those, and rewire the string into the existing 12v ac landscape lighting transformer instead of the 3v dc 500ma transformer.   ordered the bulbs already and should get them tomorrow.  if all goes well then I'll come back to update this...